# OpenERP - Get leads data in partner form view

Tags: xml, odoo

I'm trying to display lead data related to a partner.

But on module installation, I keep having the `ValidateError` saying `Error occurred while validating the field(s) arch: Invalid XML for View Architecture!`

I don't know why this is happening, cause I've double checked fields names, and compared my xml structure and content to other module xml view files.

I've also set dependencies to `'base','crm',` in `__openerp__.py`

Does anyone see something wrong in my code below ?

Here is my piece of python code:

```
class res_partner(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    _columns = {
             'lead_ids': fields.one2many('crm.lead', 'partner_id', 'Leads'),
    }
```

And here my view:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <page string="Accounting" position="after" version="7.0">
  <page string="History" name="cap_history_tab">
    <!-- Customer Leads Group -->
    <group name="grp_leads_history" string="Leads History">
          <field name="lead_ids" colspan="4" nolabel="1">
            <tree string="Partner Leads" editable="false" create="false" delete="false">
              <field name="name" readonly="True"/>
              <field name="create_date" readonly="True"/>
              <field name="date_deadline" readonly="True"/>
              <field name="priority" readonly="True"/>
              <field name="planned_revenue" readonly="True"/>
              <field name="probability" readonly="True"/>
              <field name="state" readonly="True"/>
            </tree>
          </field>
        </group>
  </page>
</page>
```

When I look to the server log here is the message :

`Can't find field 'lead_ids'  in the following view parts composing the view of object model 'res.partner'`

[EDIT]
After a while, and a another restart of the server, the problem is solved and I can see the leads.

Thanks all for your help

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
<record id="view_partner_property_form1" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">res.partner.property.form.inherit1</field>
    <field name="model">res.partner</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//notebook/page[@string='History']" position="inside">
                <!-- Customer Leads Group -->
            <group name="grp_leads_history" string="Leads History">
                <field name="lead_ids" colspan="4" nolabel="1">
                    <tree string="Partner Leads" editable="false" create="false" delete="false">
                        <field name="name" readonly="True"/>
                        <field name="create_date" readonly="True"/>
                        <field name="date_deadline" readonly="True"/>
                        <field name="priority" readonly="True"/>
                        <field name="planned_revenue" readonly="True"/>
                        <field name="probability" readonly="True"/>
                        <field name="state" readonly="True"/>
                    </tree>
                </field>
            </group>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: sure I forget to provide this detail. I edited my post

Comment: If you want to add particular place in page than you can add another xpath and position= after or before as you want. Two xpath works well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is your OpenERP version... I got it working in version 7.0 with the following xml code.

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="res_partner_test_view">
            <field name="res.partner.test.view"/>
            <field name="model">res.partner</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <page string="Accounting" position="after" version="7.0">
                  <page string="History" name="cap_history_tab">
                    <group name="grp_leads_history" string="Leads History">
                          <field name="lead_ids" colspan="4" nolabel="1">
                            <tree editable="false" create="false" delete="false" nolabel="1">
                              <field name="name" readonly="True"/>
                              <field name="create_date" readonly="True"/>
                              <field name="date_deadline" readonly="True"/>
                              <field name="priority" readonly="True"/>
                              <field name="planned_revenue" readonly="True"/>
                              <field name="probability" readonly="True"/>
                              <field name="state" readonly="True"/>
                            </tree>
                          </field>
                        </group>
                  </page>
                  </page>
                </field>
            </record>
```

Hope it helps, cheers.

PD:
I tried both ways, using position="after" and xpath expr="//page[@string='Accounting']" position="after" and both worked fine.